# Point the null value in MAX to MIN of Next Date

Tags: sql-server

[Table screen shot here][2]We have an attendance DB where we are trying to get them sorted as IN and OUT, the Query posted here

```
SELECT
  employee_code,
  CONVERT(DATE, ([attendance_date_with_time])) AS [DATE],
  MIN([attendance_date_with_time]) AS [IN],
  MAX([attendance_date_with_time]) AS [OUT] 
FROM attendanceBioMetric 
GROUP BY
  Employee_Code,
  CONVERT(DATE, ([attendance_date_with_time]))
ORDER BY [DATE] DESC
```

Gives us the data correctly for the Employees in A-shift as well as Gen-shift, because their Log-In date and Logout date falls on the same day.

Whereas for the `B-shift` employees,whose logout time falls on next date,
the OUT data is returning the MIN value as the Log-Out date is different from the Login date.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem

Thank you

Refer Pic for your reference

AttendanceBioMetric_ID  BiometricMachine_ID Employee_Code Attendance_Date_With_Time Created_Date    Status
1   1   NULL        16-07-18 5:53 PM    NULL    1
2   1   NULL        16-07-18 5:53 PM    NULL    1
3   1   NEB/0134    26-07-18 12:44 PM   NULL    1
4   1   NEB/0134    26-07-18 12:44 PM   NULL    1
5   1   NEB/0134    26-07-18 12:44 PM   NULL    1
6   1   NEB/0134    26-07-18 12:44 PM   NULL    1
7   1   NEB/0134    26-07-18 12:47 PM   NULL    1
8   1   NEB0141     26-07-18 12:47 PM   NULL    1
9   1   NEB0141     26-07-18 12:49 PM   NULL    1
10  1   NEB0141     26-07-18 12:50 PM   NULL    1
11  1   NEB0141     26-07-18 12:50 PM   NULL    1
12  1   NEB0141     26-07-18 12:50 PM   NULL    1
13  1   NEB0141     26-07-18 12:50 PM   NULL    1
14  6   NEB/0134    28-07-18 10:05 AM   NULL    1
15  6   NEB/0134    28-07-18 10:05 AM   NULL    1
16  6   SH0064      28-07-18 10:34 AM   NULL    1
17  6   SH0064      28-07-18 10:34 AM   NULL    1
18  6   SH0064      28-07-18 10:36 AM   NULL    1
19  6   SH00081     28-07-18 11:05 AM   NULL    1
20  6   NEB0141     28-07-18 11:06 AM   NULL    1
21  6   SH00081     28-07-18 11:06 AM   NULL    1
22  6   SH0064      28-07-18 11:06 AM   NULL    1

Comment: How do you determine that each entry is an *in* or an *out*? Do you *always* know they come in pairs? Or are there times when an in or out is missed? Are there other business rules that can help work this out? As it stands there is not enough data being captured to know unless there are additional rules that can be used to overlay the data.

Comment: I agree with TomC: that's not enough info. Is there at least something like max. duration of a shift? Otherwise you'll run into problems as soon as one login / logout is missed.

Comment: We have not configured any shift timing, we are simply assuming that the MIN value to be the Login Time and Max Value to be the Log out time,(for A-shift and Gen-shift) , we cross check the Login Hrs by taking the time difference between the MIN and MAX(which is not presented in the Code and done through excel), where even if the employee  misses the Punch whether he is in A-shift and Gen Shift or b-shift, we can easily find it out and Max duration we can take around 24hrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the following work for you?

I Tested it using my data, but I think it would work.

```
    SELECT
    employee_code
,   CONVERT(DATE,([attendance_date_with_time]) ) AS [DATE]
,   MIN([attendance_date_with_time]) AS [IN]
,   MAX([attendance_date_with_time]) AS [OUT]
,   case when day(MAX([attendance_date_with_time])) = day(MIN([attendance_date_with_time])) then MAX([attendance_date_with_time]) else
    when MAX([attendance_date_with_time]) is null then 
 MIN(DATEADD(day, 1, [attendance_date_with_time])) else MAX([attendance_date_with_time]) end [OUT-B]
 FROM attendanceBioMetric 
GROUP BY Employee_Code,CONVERT(DATE,([attendance_date_with_time]) ) 
order by DATE desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested script.This is just an idea.you have to manage it.

```
;with CTE as
(
select empcode from FROM attendanceBioMetric 
where shift='B'

)
,CTE1 as
(
SELECT employee_code,
  CONVERT(DATE,([attendance_date_with_time]) ) AS [DATE],
  MIN([attendance_date_with_time]) AS [IN]
,MAX([attendance_date_with_time]) AS [OUT] 
 FROM attendanceBioMetric 
GROUP BY Employee_Code,CONVERT(DATE,([attendance_date_with_time]) ) 
order by DATE desc 
)

select c1.* 
,case when c.employee_code is not null then ShiftB_LogOut
from CTE1 c1
left join cte c on c.employee_code=c1.employee_code
outer apply(select min([date])ShiftB_LogOut 
from CTE1 c2 
where c.employee_code=c1.employee_code 
and c1.date=datead(day,1,c2.date))c2
```

Comment: Assuming there is a shift column. From my reading of the question it was purely a reading of when the employee passed the scanner, with no other information.

Comment: @TomC , I clearly that this is just one idea written in notepad. Now rest only "IT Department " can make it clear.

Comment: @TomC, We have 7 biometric machines, the machines 1,2,3,4 are used for marking the IN punch and the machines 5,6,7 are used to mark the out punch, and the BiometricMachine_ID is the table where this info is stored

Comment: @ITDepartment that would have been a useful piece of information in the original question! As it was written there was no way of knowing. Try and add the table schemas in for your next question as you will get better answers. looks like you already have one that works for you.

Comment: apologies for that, next time I'll post the schema as well, "AttendanceBioMetric_ID BiometricMachine_ID Employee_Code Attendance_Date_With_Time  ", these are the table names and the typical shift timing for a shift starts at 7:30 am, G-shift starts at 9:00 am and b-shift starts at 6:00 pm

Answer (score 1):

Check the following query that runs on the guessed test data.

```
DECLARE @attendanceBioMetric TABLE(
  employee_code INT,
  attendance_date_with_time DATETIME
);

INSERT @attendanceBioMetric(employee_code, attendance_date_with_time)
VALUES
  (1, '20180902 23:58'), (1, '20180903 07:32'),
  (2, '20180903 06:57'), (2, '20180903 15:47'),
  (3, '20180903 15:28'), (3, '20180904 00:03'),
  (1, '20180903 23:42'), (1, '20180904 07:17'),
  (2, '20180904 06:57'), (2, '20180904 15:47'),
  (3, '20180904 15:28'), (3, '20180905 00:03');

SELECT
  employee_code,
  CONVERT(DATE, MIN(attendance_date_with_time)) AS [DATE],
  MIN(attendance_date_with_time) [IN],
  MAX(attendance_date_with_time) [OUT]
FROM(
  SELECT
    *,
    (ROW_NUMBER()
       OVER(PARTITION BY employee_code
            ORDER BY attendance_date_with_time)-1)/2 ioseq
  FROM @attendanceBioMetric) a
GROUP BY employee_code, ioseq;
```

To try the query online, please click [here](http://rextester.com/NPK8650).

Comment: This works as long as the data is 100% reliable. But as soon as there is a lunch break resulting in more than one pair of readings in a day, or one missed scan for any reason, it all falls in a heap.

Comment: Each employee is supposed to punch only two times, i.e IN and OUT,